# GDB or GDB-oneAPI freezing when displaying complex variables in VSCode

Tags: variables, debugging, gdb, vscode-debugger, intel-oneapi

I am experiencing an issue with both gdb and gdb-oneAPI(intel oneAPI) in Visual Studio Code on Linux where the debugger freezes when trying to display complex variables, such as containers. I have tried updating gdb-oneapi and installing the C/C++ Extension Pack, but the issue persists.

When debugging, the next line can be executed normally without displaying variables. Simple variables are displayed well. It freezes when displaying complex lists, multimaps, etc.